# Como separar um dígito de um número inteiro?

Tags: python

Por exemplo, para o programa dizer o número da casa das centenas de um número a partir de:

```
número_int = int(input("Digite um número inteiro: "))
```

Comment: Se usuário digitar 123, o programa deve retornar 1?

Comment: Exatamente, mas não faço ideia de como fazer isso

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para pegar o dígito da centena, basta dividir o valor por 100, pegar apenas a parte inteira do resultado e, se houver mais dígitos, pegar o último da sequência.

```
>>> numero_int = 5
>>> print(int(str(int(numero_int/100))[-1]))
0

>>> numero_int = 123
>>> print(int(str(int(numero_int/100))[-1]))
1

>>> numero_int = 14589
>>> print(int(str(int(numero_int/100))[-1]))
5
```

Por partes:

```
int(numero_int/100)
```

Pega a parte inteira do resultado da divisão do número por 100.

```
str(...)[-1]
```

Converte o valor para *string* e busca apenas o último caractere. Isto porquê se o número for maior que 1000, a parte inteira da divisão por 100 será maior que 10. Por exemplo: `int(14589/100)` será 14, o que queremos é 4.

```
int(...)
```

Converte o último caractere da *string* para *int* novamente.

> Para pegar a parte inteira da divisão, também é possível utilizar o operador `//`, tal como em `numero_int // 100`, sendo o equivalente de `int(numero_int / 100)`.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução é dividir inteiro por uma potência de 10, e usar a operação de resto da divisão por 10. Por exemplo, em Python 2 para obter o terceiro dígito da direita para a esquerda:

```
>>> 9912345 / 100 % 10
3
```

Em Python 3 uma divisão entre inteiros retorna um float, então é preciso usar o operador de divisão inteira (funciona em Python 2.7 também):

```
>>> 9912345 // 100 % 10
3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num = 1894

unidade = num // 1 % 10 # 4
dezena = num // 10 % 10 # 9 
centena = num // 100 % 10 # 8 
milhar = num // 1000 % 10 # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Transforma para String, depois aponta o local do número.

```
num = int(input('Entre com um número de 0 a 9999: '))
n = str(num)

print('\nAnalizando o número {}'.format(n)) 
print('\nUnidade: {}'
    '\nDezena: {}'
    '\nCentena: {}'
    '\nMilhar: {}'
    .format(n[3], n[2], n[1], n[0]) 
      )
```

Answer (score -2):

num = int(input('Informe Um Número: '))
u = num // 1 % 10
d = num // 10 % 10
c = num // 100 % 10
m = num // 1000 % 10
print('Analizando o Número {}'.format(num))
print('Unidade {}:''\nDezena {}:''\nCentena {}:''\nMilhar: {}'.format(u, d, c, m))